# Is it possible to include a path in an 'includepdf' command?

Tags: pdfpages

I have been using an includepdf command thus, after defining 'moniker' and 'module' (e.g. moniker=m, module=8:

```
\includepdf[fitpaper]{front-\moniker\module}
```

In which case, this would include PDF named 'front-m8.pdf'.

I would like to alter this to use a folder structure instead, e.g. where m8 is the enclosing folder.

```
\includepdf[fitpaper]{\moniker\module/front}
```

In which case, this would include PDF named 'm8/front.pdf'.

(Note: moniker and module are repeatedly redefined, in multiple documents, using same document.tex to load different pages)

I understood that tex ignores folders and just looks in the whole …/tex/latex/… folder structure, but I'm unsure — is there a syntax for including a folder in a string like this?

Comment: Have you tried?  I would expect this to work just fine, with the `m8` directory in the same directory as your main tex file.

Comment: How about this? ```\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{cover.pdf}```

Comment: tex does not ignore specified folders

Comment: It worked. Thank you for inputs.